# SQL query for messages database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make messaging system similar to facebook. I know how to show all messages between 2 users, but I don't know how to make this

[image]

This is my database

[image]

Comment: Did you even try doing it by yourself?

Comment: Yes, I've been trying for 2 days. I can post my query just to let you know how far I've came

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is basically this, but the performance can become really crappy if it starts to grow.

```
SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, body, is_read
FROM table
WHERE deleted_by IS NULL AND receiver_id = x
-- WHERE deleted_by IS NULL AND (sender_id = x OR receiver_id = x)
GROUP BY sender_id, receiver_id
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Do note that this is a group by without explicit handling of the non-grouped columns which only works in MySQL. In PostgreSQL you could solve this cleanly with `DISTINCT ON()` but this should do the trick for MySQL.

Comment: pretty good, but when senders sends messages it shows that he has unread messages and on receiver's side it shows no new messages

Comment: Ok, in that case you might simply want to have the `receiver_id` filter instead of the `receiver_id OR sender_id` :)